# Using pointers to muliply numbers bigger then intMAX

Tags: c++, pointers

I have 2 very big numbers that are stored in pointers, for example the number:1234567891234567891234567890 is stored: 123 456 789 012 345 678 901 234 567 890. With to of those big number I need to do multiplication and store it in another pointer.
A cijfervakje is one of those groups of 3.
gg&object, is the adres too the number.

I thing that the problem I have is that I don't access the cijvervakjes correct for the big numbers, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
void gg::multi(gg & objectA, gg & objectB){
    cijfervakje * helpA = objectA.exit;
    cijfervakje* helpB = objectB.exit;
    int numberA = 0; int numberB = 0; int carry = 0;
    int ans; int length;
    gg * helpLijst = new gg;

    delete(); //empties the list where the answer will go.

    while (helpA != nullptr || helpB != nullptr) {
        numberA = 0; numberB = 0;
        if(helpA != nullptr) {
            numberA = numberA -> info;
            helpA = helpA -> vorige;
        }
        if (helpB != nullptr) {
            numberB = helpB -> info;
            helpB = helpB -> vorige;
        }
        ans = numberA * numberB;
        carry = 0; //Reset the carry
        length = meetLengte(ans);
        if(length > k) {
            carry = ans / tienTotDeMacht(k); //determine first number.
            ans -= carry * tienTotDeMacht(k); /// remove first number
        }
        addBefore(ans, length);
    }
}
```

---

```
class cijfervakje {
public:
    cijfervakje* vorige;
    int info; //Geeft het getal in dit vakje.
    int lengte; //Geeft de lengte van het getal in dit vakje.
    cijfervakje* volgende;
};
```

if any more code or explanation is needed, please ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, some of your question doesn't make sense. First, don't use pointers to do math. I don't think that's actually what you're doing, though.

You're using pointers to objects of type cijfervakje, but you don't provide that code, so we have no idea what that does.

Do you know about the different types of integers in C++? You can use:

int typically 4 bytes
long might be 4 or 8 bytes
long long typically 8 bytes for values up to 18 billion billion 2^64.

You can't do anything in a pointer you can't do in a long long.

But it may be that the class you're using actually does long math. If so, we need to know more about that class to help you.